# Extract XML header information into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

My process involves getting a large XML file on a daily basis.
I have developed an SSIS package (2008 r2) which first gets rid of the multiple namespaces via a XSLT and then imports data into 40 tables (due to its complexity) by using the XML source object.

Here is the watered down version of a test xml file

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Test xmlns:s="http://@@@.@@.com/xml"              
<sequence>62</sequence>

<generated>2015-04-28T00:59:38</generated>
<report_date>2015-04-27</report_date>

    <orders>    
        <order>
        </order>
    </orders>
```

My question is: The  XML source imports all the Orders with its nested attributes. How do I extract the 'report_date' and 'generated' from the header?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XML method [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) passing proper XPath/XQuery expression as parameter. For demo, consider the following table and data :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (id int, MyXmlColumn XML)
DECLARE @data XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Test xmlns:s="http://@@@.@@.com/xml">              
    <sequence>62</sequence>

    <generated>2015-04-28T00:59:38</generated>
    <report_date>2015-04-27</report_date>

    <orders>    
        <order>
        </order>
    </orders>
</s:Test>'
INSERT INTO Mytable VALUES(1,@data)
```

You can use the following query to get `generated` and `report_date` data :

```
SELECT
    t.MyXmlColumn.value('(/*/generated)[1]','datetime') as generated
    , t.MyXmlColumn.value('(/*/report_date)[1]','date') as report_date
FROM Mytable t
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f91f/1)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
generated               report_date
----------------------- -----------
2015-04-28 00:59:38.000 2015-04-27
```